# How do I fetch a named constant value with its name concatenated from two cell values?

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel named constant named "SheepGrams", with a value of 500. I need values for other animals, too, e.g. "PigGrams", "ChickGrams". I want to fetch their values by concatenating cell values.

=INDIRECT(A1&B1) works with named ranges only, where A1 contains "Pig" and B1 contains "Grams". It will not return named constants values

=INDIRECT(A1&B1) returns #REF, but works if the result is a named range, not a named constant in Name Manager

Comment: This sounds like a design flaw. Most of the time, if you are using `INDIRECT`, there's a better way to do things. Why don't you just create a lookup table in one of your sheets that defines these values for these different "grams" values and then just reference this table when you need one of these values?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a limitation of named constants as they don't return a range, so `Indirect()` doesn't know what to do with the return that the name is giving back.

As a possible workaround you could hinky up a UDF like:

```
Public Function INDIRECT2(rangeName As String) As String
    INDIRECT2 = Split(ThisWorkbook.Names(rangeName).RefersTo, "=")(1)
End Function
```

Or you could plunk your constants down in another sheet and use named ranges so you can pull off whatever you are trying to do.